# what is the difference between Hadoop batch analytics and hadoop real time analytics

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

*I want to know the difference between Hadoop batch analytics and Hadoop real time analytics*.

E.g `Hadoop real time analytics` can be done using `Apache Spark` while `Hadoop batch analytics` can be done using `Map reduce` programming.

Also if real time analytics is the more preferred one then what is batch analytics required for?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Batch means you process aaaaaaall data you have collected so far. Real-time means you process data as it enters the system. Neither one is "preferred".

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain use cases for Batch processing & Real processing.

**Batch processing:**

In stock market application, you have requirement to provide below summary data on daily basis

1. For each stock, total number of buy orders and sum of all buy orders
2. For each stock, total number of sell order and sum of all sell orders
3. For each stock, total number of successful orders & failed orders

   etc.

Here need 24 hours of stock market data to generate these reports.

** Weather application: **

Save weather reports of all places in the world for all countries. For a given place like Newyork or Country like America, find hottest and coldest day since 1900. This query requires huge input data sets which requires processing on thousands of noudes.

You can use ***`Hadoop Map Reduce job`*** to provide above summary. You may have to process Peta bytes of data, which is stored in 4000+ servers in Hadoop cluster.

**Real time analytics:**

Another use case, you logged into social networking site like facebook or twitter. Your friends posted a message on your wall or tweeted in twitter. You have to get these notification in real time.

When you visit sites like Booking.com to book a hotel, You will get real time notifications like X users are currently viewing this hotel etc. These notifications are generated in real time.

In above use cases, system should process streams of data and generate real time notifications to users instead of waiting for one day data. Spark streaming provides excellent support to handle these type of scenarios.

Spark uses in - memory processing for faster query execution but it's not possible to always use in - memory for peta bytes of  data. Spark can process terabytes of data and Hadoop can process Peta bytes of data.

Comment: I'd consider stock market real time. Stock trading, fluctuating prices, etc

Comment: Just to showcase peta bytes of data for generation of summary reports, I have used it for batch processing example.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop batch analytics and real time analytics both are totally different, It depends on your use case what you want, example - you have a large volume of row dataset and you want to extract only few information from that dataset, information may be based on some calculation/trending etc. than this can be done with batch processing like finding a minimum temperature since last 50 years.

Whereas real time analytics, means you need the expected output ASAP like your friend tweeted on twitter and you get the tweets as soon as tweeted by your friend.

Comment: Twitted? It's tweeted. And you get tweets, not twits

Answer (score 0):

Batch data processing is an efficient way of processing high volumes of data is where a group of transactions is collected over a period of time. Data is collected, entered, processed and then the batch results are produced (Hadoop focused on batch data processing). Batch processing requires separate programs for input, process and output. An example is payroll and billing systems.

In contrast, real time data processing involves a continual input, process and output of data. Data must be processed in a small time period (or near real time). Radar systems, customer services and bank ATMs are examples.